# Webpacker Error on creating new rails app in rails 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When i am creating new rails application i am getting error with webpacker (ArgumentError: Malformed version number string 0.32+git)

Comment: Hi, can you paste in the complete command you type when creating the application?

Comment: rails new "app_name" -d mysql,                                                                                   my rails version is 6.0.0

Answer (score 24):

I was running into a similar issue running rails 6 on my Docker container. Turns out Rails 6 uses `Webpacker`, which needs yarn to be installed. Follow steps to install a [newer version of Yarn](https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/install/#mac-stable)

For Debian make sure these steps are followed

```
curl -sS https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | sudo apt-key add -
echo "deb https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list
```

and then 
`sudo apt update && sudo apt install yarn`

This gave me `yarn --version` -> `1.19.1`

after which sample `rails new blog` ran successfully, and added `blog/config/webpacker.yml`  (Related to [Vanilla Rails 6.0: "error Command "webpack" not found"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58065428/vanilla-rails-6-0-error-command-webpack-not-found))

It is strange that the documentation does not mention `yarn` as a dependency.

Answer (score 3):

I confronted the same issue and resolved by installing yarn using nvm.

```
npm install -g yarn
```

After installing and updating yarn to the current version, I have my Webpacker successfully installed.

Answer (score 3):

I installed yarn by running `sudo apt-get installed yarn` on my POP OS(Ubuntu under the hood), and get the same error as yours.

Then, I have fixed this error by following the steps at yarn official page, https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/install/#debian-stable

`curl -sS https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | sudo apt-key add -`

`echo "deb https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list`

Then,
`sudo apt-get update`

Finally,
`sudo apt-get install yarn`

Answer (score 2):

I should say this error was a step two error, I first had this other highly related problem [Vanilla Rails 6.0: "error Command "webpack" not found"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58065428/vanilla-rails-6-0-error-command-webpack-not-found) and then I was led here.

Here is what I did to solve it. +32 was indeed coming from yarn

```
$ yarn --version
0.32+git
```

I tried to find the lucky combination of node/npm/yarn/webpack
but I never won anything at the lottery

so I removed yarn...

- open your `package.json` in your favorite editor
- make sure `yarn` is NOT there
- delete yarn, or rename the binary
- `rails webpacker:install` # now happy
- `rake assets:precompile` # also happy
- `rails s` # works fine again, I can use ActionCable finally.

Answer (score 1):

npm ls -g

if no list yarn.

sudo npm install -g yarn --force

then

yarn --version

Answer (score 0):

If you put 0.32+git as version number please try using a numeric version number, eg: 0.32 (drop the +git)

Answer (score 0):

Try to update your Yarn version. Webpacker uses Yarn and it probably won't work with an old version, such as "0.32+git".
When I updated my version, the problem got solved and I could run the rails application.