# Rails: Vanilla Rails 6.0 error Command "webpack" not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpack, ruby-on-rails-6

### System:

Ruby: 2.6.3p62 (rvm)
Rails: 6.0
OS: macOS 10.14.6

### Setup

A fresh Rails 6.0 application:

```
$ rails new testshop2
$ cd testshop2
$ rails g controller Page index
$ rails s
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 6.0.0 application starting in development 
=> Run `rails server --help` for more startup options
Puma starting in single mode...
* Version 3.12.1 (ruby 2.6.3-p62), codename: Llamas in Pajamas
* Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
* Environment: development
* Listening on tcp://localhost:3000
Use Ctrl-C to stop
```

When I browse to `http://localhost:3000/page/index' the system throughs this error:

```
Started GET "/page/index" for ::1 at 2019-09-23 17:06:12 +0200
  (0.4ms)  SELECT sqlite_version(*)
Processing by PageController#index as HTML
  Rendering page/index.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered page/index.html.erb within layouts/application (Duration: 1.8ms | Allocations: 206)
[Webpacker] Compiling…
[Webpacker] Compilation failed:
error Command "webpack" not found.

Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 2021ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms | Allocations: 640080)



ActionView::Template::Error (Webpacker can't find application in /Users/stefan/Github/sandbox/testshop2/public/packs/manifest.json. Possible causes:
1. You want to set webpacker.yml value of compile to true for your environment
  unless you are using the `webpack -w` or the webpack-dev-server.
2. webpack has not yet re-run to reflect updates.
3. You have misconfigured Webpacker's config/webpacker.yml file.
4. Your webpack configuration is not creating a manifest.
Your manifest contains:
{
}
):
    6:     <%= csp_meta_tag %>
    7: 
    8:     <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    9:     <%= javascript_pack_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    10:   </head>
    11: 
    12:   <body>

app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:9
```

How can I fix this? It says `error Command "webpack" not found.` but shouldn't Rails install everything needed automatically?

Comment: For anyone stopping by today, as a note: Node v16 does not seem well liked by webpacker. Try v14

Answer (score 14):

I faced the same issue. And tried running `bundle exec rails webpacker:install` as suggested by @AFOC 's answer. Then I realized my node version wasn't compatible with rails/webpacker. Then used node 12.x. it works.

I also I retried by deleting the whole app, creating the app again, did not face the issue again, it worked the first time. So in my case, it was node version.

Comment: This command by itself actually got me a ways down the road.  I'm still having issues with the webpack config, but this moved me past the issue.  Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

I had to same challenge when trying to set up a new **Rails 6** application in **Ubuntu 20.04**.

When I start the rails server, I get the error:

```
error Command "webpack" not found.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
09:17:58 webpacker.1 | exited with code 1
09:17:58 system      | sending SIGTERM to all processes
09:17:58 watcher.1   | exited with code 1
09:17:58 web.1       | terminated by SIGTERM
```

**Here's how I fixed it**:

The issue for me was due to poor internet connectivity, which did not permit the full installation of `webpacker` and all of its dependencies. So each time I run the command:

```
bundle exec rails webpacker:install
```

I get this output:

```
Installing all JavaScript dependencies [4.3.0]
         run  yarn add @rails/webpacker@4.3.0 from "."
yarn add v1.22.5
[1/4] Resolving packages...
info There appears to be trouble with your network connection. Retrying...
info There appears to be trouble with your network connection. Retrying...
```

I simply had to move to an area with better internet connectivity, and then I ran the  command:

```
bundle exec rails webpacker:install
```

OR

```
rails webpacker:install
```

This time, it ran successfully and installed `webpacker` and all of its dependencies, and it gave me this final output:

```
[4/4] Building fresh packages...
success Saved 1 new dependency.
info Direct dependencies
└─ webpack-dev-server@3.11.0
info All dependencies
└─ webpack-dev-server@3.11.0
Done in 5.90s.
```

Comment: bundle exec rails webpacker:install

./bin/webpack-dev-server
it worked

Comment: Perfect answer: `rails webpacker:install` simple as that, thanks!

Answer (score 8):

The problem comes from the version of node on your local computer. When you created your rails app, you probably had an error like this pop up:

```
The JavaScript app source directory already exists
   apply  /Users/mconiaris/.rbenv/versions/2.6.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/webpacker-4.0.7/lib/install/binstubs.rb
  Copying binstubs
       exist    bin
      create    bin/webpack
      create    bin/webpack-dev-server
      append  .gitignore
Installing all JavaScript dependencies [4.0.7]
         run  yarn add @rails/webpacker from "."
yarn add v1.17.3
info No lockfile found.
[1/4]   Resolving packages...
warning @rails/webpacker > postcss-preset-env > postcss-color-functional-notation > postcss-values-parser > flatten@1.0.2: I wrote this module a very long time ago; you should use something else.
[2/4]   Fetching packages...
error get-caller-file@2.0.5: The engine "node" is incompatible with this module. Expected version "6.* || 8.* || >= 10.*". Got "9.4.0"
error Found incompatible module.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/add for documentation about this command.
```

In my case, I had version 9.4.0 of node installed on my computer, and that was the one version the get-caller-file package did not want to work with.

To fix the problem, first confirm your version of node to ensure that it's not 9.x.x:

```
node -v
```

Update node (I use nvm, but there are [other ways on GitHub](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm) on the [node](https://nodejs.org/en/) Website).

```
nvm install node # "node" is an alias for the latest version
```

Check the version again. If it's 12.10 or higher, you should be all set.

Go start another brand new rails project and it should work fine.

Comment: How's node v10.15.2 ? should that be supported? How do we find out what version of webpacker needs what version of node? etc?

Comment: I am on ubuntu and I ran `snap install node --edge --classic` I now have node `13.0.0-nightly` instead of `10.15`, hopefully that works better

Comment: probably also very important, how compatible is `npm@6.10.3` with all of this?

Comment: The only indication that I got regarding the node version being the issue what when I created the app or specifically tried to yarn add webpacker.

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem on a fresh 6.0 install too, in my case it had nothing to do with node or yarn to my knowledge. I noticed there was no mention of webpack in package.json, so I ran `yarn add webpack` and tried again. I got the following that said it compiled, but the page still didn't load:

```
[Webpacker] Compiled all packs in /vagrant/revmtg/RevMtg/public/packs
[Webpacker] One CLI for webpack must be installed. These are recommended choices, delivered as separate packages:
 - webpack-cli (https://github.com/webpack/webpack-cli)
   The original webpack full-featured CLI.
```

So I ran `yarn add webpack-cli`. Then I got `Error: Cannot find module '@rails/webpacker'`.

So I deleted the `node_modules` folder and then ran `bundle exec rails webpacker:install`. After that it finally worked.

Edit: Just in case you're running on a Vagrant VM in Windows make sure you start it as administrator, otherwise adding dependencies via yarn might fail.

Answer (score 3):

Try doing :

```
bundle exec rails webpacker:install
```

if it is still not working than try:

```
 npm install
yarn install check--files
```

Answer (score 3):

Check the yarn package installed. In my case the yarn version was not compatible with rails. Run below command:

***yarn add @rails/webpacker***

Answer (score 1):

I ended up removing yarn.
After solving the error presented in this question, I had another problem with yarn.
I don't know if I should cross-post my solution, since it is the same. or just link to it

https://stackoverflow.com/a/58100373/683982

Hope this helps someone

Answer (score 1):

This means webpacker somehow is missing or uninstalled in your application.

```
rails webpacker:install
```

Should fix your problem.